# Can't call calculated field rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a really simple cost model which belongs to an order.

Each cost has a value and quantity and I'm calculating the total using:

```
def set_total
    @set_total = quantity * amount
end
```

This works great and in my costs views, I can call with:

```
<td><%= number_to_currency(cost.set_total, :unit => "&pound;") %></td>
```

However, I don't seem to be able to show this in my orders show view - get a NoMethodError:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.*
```

In orders, show, I have this:

```
<% unless @order.costs.empty? %>
<% @order.costs.each do |cost| %>  
    <%= cost.description %>
    <%= cost.cost_type %>
    <%= number_to_currency(cost.amount, :unit => "&pound;") %>
    <%= cost.quantity %>
    <%= cost.set_total %>     
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

My routes are setup fine:

```
resources :orders do
  :costs
end
```

If I use a table to display the information, I get a blank line at the end. Costs partial:

```
 <% unless @order.costs.empty? %>
        <table border='1' cellpadding="5">
          <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>

          </tr>
        <% @order.costs.each do |cost| %> 
          <tr>
            <td><%= cost.description %></td>
            <td><%= cost.cost_type %></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(cost.amount, :unit => "&pound;") %></td>
        <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>   
        <td><%= cost.set_total %></td>  

          </tr>
        <% end %>
        </table>
        <% end %>
```

Can see an extra table row at the bottom and can't see why. Think this is leading to the nil value.

--edit--

With debugging on, I can still see extra lines:

```
!ruby/ActiveRecord:Cost 
  attributes: 
    description: 
    cost_type: 
    amount: 
    order_id: 14
    code: 
    created_at: 
    updated_at: 
    quantity:
```

Which doesn't make sense because I've just reset the db... Why is a blank cost created, with no ID even.

UPDATE

```
class CostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
    @costs = Cost.paginate(:per_page => 3, :page => params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @costs }
  end
  end

  def show
        @costs = Cost.find(params[:id])
    end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end
  def create
      @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
      @cost = @order.costs.create(params[:cost])
      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    end
end
```

Comment: can you stick in the actual exception itself? Youd don't need the entire thing, but perhaps the first 2 or 3 lines?

Comment: See amended edit.. Jenny

Comment: can you post the trace of the MoMethodError? like the line numbers, and corresponding file

Comment: if you just set `set total` to do `return 0` what happens

Answer (score 1):

`The error occurred while evaluating nil.*` that error mean that you trying to call `*` method on the `nil` object.

```
def set_total
 @set_total = quantity * amount
end
```

Make sure that  `quantity` attribute is set to not nil value for each `Cost` record.

or change your method to:

```
def set_total
 @set_total = (quantity || 0) * amount
end
```

Comment: Hi, I've checked this again and again as I thought it was the issue. However, all the costs have a quantity - it's a required field. What is a bit weird though is that I seem to have an extra line added on the costs table. I've added my costs view to edit. Thanks Jx

Comment: The part where it says it's expecting an array is what confuses me ("You might have expected an instance of Array"). Are you certain it is the set_total that is the issue? Perhaps it's that you don't have a cost at all in one of your executions. I can email you a chicken to sacrifice if you think that might help :)

Comment: A chicken would be fantastic! No, I don't think it's the field, I think it's my view. Why would I end up with another row in my table with that show?!

Comment: Yeah, this is weird. Even on an order with zero costs, there is still a table showing. I've specifically included <% unless @order.costs.empty? %> so I don't see what the table's there

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post your controller code ?
I would think that you build a new cost in your controller, using something like `@orders.costs.new` or `@orders.costs.build` ?
Your last comment about the table showing even if there are no cost for this order validate this hypothesis

UPDATE:

Also for the method set_total, you should consider to refactor it to :

```
def total
  @total ||= quantity.to_i * amount
end
```

Using this code the total value will be cached for other called to `total` on this object.
Using total instead of set_total for the name of the method is more close to the ruby/rails convention.

Comment: Hi. I've updated my initial post with my costs controller. Interestingly, this controller was taken directly from our comments controller which doesn't see the same null field created. J

Comment: I do not see the creation of another cost in your controller but I still think it should be the problem. Do you have a form for new comment in the page you are displaying ? If so, how do you display the form for this new comment ?

Comment: sorry, typo "comment" instead of "cost"

Comment: Hi, it would seem my code is creating a blank comment:  <%= form_for([@order, @order.costs.build]) do |f| %> What's the best way to deal with that?

Comment: Ok so you are building a new comment here. When you call `@order.costs` after this line, it returns the list with this new comment included. To prevent it, you can use `@costs` (which is already set in your controller) to display the list of costs, it shouldn't contain the new cost because you are saving it before creating a new cost.

Answer (score 0):

There is something up with your costs.

when you create then are you  using `@order.costs.new(....)`
make sure you save them after that, that could be the problem.

Try using the console to create and play with an object, see if it is failing validation, not saving etc

Comment: Hi. It looks fine in the console. For some reason, when I load an order, it's building a null cost associated. Have pasted my controller in my initial edit. Thanks, Jx

Comment: what does your DB look like. what are the columns. if you do `./script/dbconsole` and do `show fields from costs` ( on MySQL at least, adapt to your db ) is there a field called order_id in the db